# JHipster using 2 authentication types together

Tags: java, spring-security, jhipster, xauth

Working on a jhipster project and love it. Its fantastic.

I am wondering if its possible to have both session based and x-auth-token or oauth together ?

We want our users to be able to access the the web interface but also call the API from server code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there any reason not to have web and API access via existing OAuth2 - see an example here: [jhipster oauth : How can i get the access_token via CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269487/jhipster-oauth-how-can-i-get-the-access-token-via-curl)

Comment: Just the complexity mainly, OAuth can be complex for old fashioned backend systems and I want to make things as simple as possible. I have checked and the x-auth-token works for the frontend site as well. Thanks