# Get access token from JHipster with OAuth2

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, jhipster

I'm reading about this OAuth2 but I can't find anything to get my token from JHipster I saw an api to connect to google , facebook... but nothing to JHipster.

My JHipster is already set up and running but i can't find this url/methods.

Does JHipster come with default url to get request and access token? and how can I retrieve that from my android app?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269487/jhipster-oauth-how-can-i-get-the-access-token-via-curl/28278293#28278293

Comment: check this here : -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692496/jhipster-oauth-how-can-i-get-the-token-via-curl/33793263#33793263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ​http://localhost:8080/oauth/token

Look at src/main/webapp/scripts/components/auth/provider/auth.oauth2.service.js for more information.