# jhipster oauth : How can i get the token via CURL

Tags: angularjs, curl, oauth, jhipster

I am trying to use the jhipster to create a new project with the oauth2 authentication. The project example works fine, I can login with the angularjs interface. However when I try to retrieve an access_token using CURL in the command line, I get response as :

> "error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials"

Can someone help me on how to use curl to get the access_token?

Comment: You'll need to show your code.

Comment: Have a look at the Gatling performance tests, I'm doing the exact same thing there, and it's working

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/token --request POST --insecure --data 
"username=[xxx]&password=[yyy]&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&    
client_secret=[your app secret]&client_id=[your app id] " -H     
"Authorization:Basic [base64 of your appid:appsecrt]"
```

Answer (score 0):

uncomment cors in application.yml inside jhipster

```
cors: #By default CORS are not enabled. Uncomment to enable.
        allowed-origins: "*"
        allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
        allowed-headers: "*"
        exposed-headers:
        allow-credentials: true
        max-age: 1800
```

To access REST API with Oauth2 authentication in ionic you must first get the token in ionic app by

```
$http({
    method: "post", 
    url: "http://192.168.0.4:8085/[Your app name]/oauth/token",
    data:  "username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=read write&client_secret=my-secret-token-to-change-in-production&client_id=auth2Sconnectapp",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'YXV0aDJTY29ubmVjdGFwcDpteS1zZWNyZXQtdG9rZW4tdG8tY2hhbmdlLWluLXByb2R1Y3Rpb24='
      }
  })                
  .success(function(data) {
      alert("success: " + data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status) {
      alert("ERROR: " + data);
  });
```

here "YXV0aDJTY29ubmVjdGFwcDpteS1zZWNyZXQtdG9rZW4tdG8tY2hhbmdlLWluLXByb2R1Y3Rpb24=" is equal to (clientId + ":" + clientSecret)--all base64-encoded

you can use https://www.base64encode.org/ to verify or recreate it for yourself

the aboue $http if successful will give you this JSON which contains token and it's expiry time

```
{
  "access_token": "2ce14f67-e91b-411e-89fa-8169e11a1c04",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "37baee3c-f4fe-4340-8997-8d7849821d00",
  "expires_in": 525,
  "scope": "read write"
}
```

take notice of "access_token" and "token_type" if you want to access any API this is what you have to use. We send the token with API to access data until the token expires then we either refresh it or access for a new one.
for example

```
$http({
    method: "get", 
    url: "http://192.168.0.4:8085/auth-2-sconnect/api/countries",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Authorization':' [token_type] + [space] + [access_token] '
      }
  })                
  .success(function(data) {
      alert("success: " + data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status) {
      alert("ERROR: " + data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it:

> 1. Just open FireBug in Firefox browser, simulate the login process with the right credentials
> 2. Locate the login request in the "NET" tab.
> 3. Right-click on it then click on "Copy as cURL"
> 4. Paste the copied value in the terminal to see what is expected to be in your cURL request: it looks verbose but you can omit certain
>      parameters. The required parameters are mentioned in @Rajender Saini answer
>      up there.

All is done.

Comment: I did the same thing with Chrome. It didn't work. It showed "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found" though I already uncommented "cors" configuration in application.yml of JHipster.